# Manipulate Random forest to produce a score rather than 0/1 label

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Here is my situation: I am able to use `random forest` to do binary classification problem; note that given a feature vector, a typical `random forest` model can predict whether it is belonging to group `1` or group `0`, thus making a binary classification.

However, due to multiple reasons, for each feature vector, I want to have a score ranging from 0 to 1 instead of the `0/1` label. Idealy, the higher the score is, I have more confidence that the feature vector should be put into the `1` set, otherwise, it should belong to the `0` set.

**So it is still a `0/1` classification, but this time, I want to have a score ranging from 0 to 1, instead of the `0` or `1` label.**

I was told that some statistic classification method, such as `naive Bayes`, can generate the possibility score, representing whether a given feature vector should be put into `0` set or `1` set. However, I did a quick 10-fold validation using `naive Bayes` on my data set, and comparing with `random forest`, the performance looks very bad.

```
                precision    recall 
random forest   0.901        0.907
naive  Bayes    0.752        0.653
```

Too bad... I want to keep the high performance of `random forest`, as well as acquring a `score`..

I am aware that `random forest` has a special tree-like structure, and as a newbie to machine learning, I have no idea how to manipulate `random forest` to generate the score.

So here is my question, how manipulate `random forest` to generate a score ranging from 0 to 1, instead of the `0` or `1` label, given a feature vector sample? Am I clear enough? Thank you!

Comment: Can't your RandomForest library deliver these? sklearns RandomForests [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) are doing this to provide probabilities: *The predicted class probabilities of an input sample is computed as the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf.* [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)

Comment: @sascha, Thank you for your reply. I am using Sklearn library.

Comment: Can `sklearn` support this? let me take a look...

Comment: Then just use obj.predict_proba(X) instead of obj.predict(X)

Comment: And one more remark for the perfectionist: it's possible to improve these probabilities a-posteriori like described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html#calibration). Although this part of sklearn is not as nice as the others (features, design, ability to add to piped gridsearches and co).

Comment: @sascha, thank you so much for saving my ass :) This is very important to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normally feature of random forest. The easiest way to get this is: each tree in the forest gives a decision on 0/1. Take the average of the decisions. You'll now get a score in [0,1] range.

If your random forest package doesn't provide this feature, you should look for another implementation that does (or check the documentation, you may have missed it).

For example, in scikit learn you call the `predict_proba` method to get probabilities and just `predict` to get the decision.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you a lot!